# symfony 4 and php version support

Tags: php, symfony, version

I have installed `Symfony 2` in the past and it worked very well with `PHP 5`. Now, after migrating my Debian system to Stretch (Debian 9), I got `php7.0.19` installed automatically. When I then try to create a new Symfony project using either `Symfony 3.3 or 4`,

I get the following error message:

> InvalidArgumentException]
>     Could not find package symfony/skeleton with stability stable in a version installable using your PHP version 7.0.19.

Comment: Symfony 4 requires PHP >= 7.1.3

Comment: [symfony/skeleton 3.3](https://github.com/symfony/skeleton/blob/3.3/composer.json) current also requires >= 7.1.3 If using composer require symfony/symfony, or symfony/symfony-standard otherwise use the [Symfony Installer](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup.html)

Comment: Php7.0 is nearing its end of life. You should upgrade to 7.1 now and make your life easier in the future, rather than avoiding the inevitable now.

Answer (score 0):

I have PHP version 7.0.21 and am using Symfony 3.3.

You can create a project with a certain version from the command line using:

```
symfony new my_project_name 3.3
```

See this reference: https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup.html#basing-your-project-on-a-specific-symfony-version

Then you can edit the composer.json file and add:

```
"require": {
  ...
  "symfony/symfony": "3.3.*",
  ...
```

So it doesn't get upgraded.

Comment: Just FYI: The use of the Symfony Installer to create new applications is no longer recommended since Symfony 3.3. Use the Composer create-project command instead.

https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/setup/flex.html

Comment: @Xosofox, your statement is incorrect. Like I said: with Symfony 3.3 you can follow the instructions I indicate. You **can** using Composer via flex instead to install (which I'm aware of), but the old command works as well - I use it all the time!

Comment: Since my "statement" is a direct copy&paste citation of the docs (see link), I'd not consider it as incorrect but an official fact... We can agree on the fact, that "both works for 3.3", though (depending on the installed php version)

Answer (score 0):

to start with - thanks a lot for the prompt answers! There is no PHP 7.1 package available so far on Debian 9. So, as suggested in https://www.goivvy.com/blog/php-7-debian-9, I will have to compile PHP using a downloaded source tarball. The example given there (./configure --with-mcrypt) suggests a minimum of options. I use mysql (utf8mb4) and apache2. Can anybody suggest addtional options for ./configure? as --help lists a ton of stuff which I am not really on top of. 
Thanks in advance for your very valuable help!
H. Stoellinger

Answer (score 0):

If you need PHP 7.1 for Symfony 4.

On Debian Jessie or Stretch, just use Sury's repos :)

https://deb.sury.org/

Answer (score 0):

I think it comes down to what you actually do when you say

> When I then try to create a new Symfony project

You need to be aware of php version requirements for

a) the installer

b) the project

If you try to have your project (3.4 or 4.0) set up via the "new flex way" (and the error indicates you are doing this) with

```
composer create-project symfony/skeleton my-project
```

you will need php 7.1 as **FLEX requires php 7.1** - no matter if you want to have your project being a 3.4 or 4.0 project

If you use "the old way"

```
symfony new my_project_name
```

you will be fine with php 5.5 as flex is not involved and 3.4 requires only php 5.5.x (https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/reference/requirements.html)